# Can JBoss 5 application access jars outside the EAR structure

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x, classloader

When the jars are packaged within EAR/lib, all works fine, but I cannot use this 
approach and need to refer to them from the filesystem (maybe using absolute/relative paths)
Also adding the jars to the system classpath (using conf/jboss-service.xml) is not an option.

I have already defined a scoped classloading using loader-repository for the app in jboss-app.xml

Is there a way the scoped classloader for the app can access libraries from outside the EAR structure?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, yes, at least with JBoss 4.2, and with luck it'll work in 5 as well.

This takes advantage of the fact that when JBoss's `EARDeployer` reads the path of each library in the `application.xml` file, it resolves the path relative to the base directory of the exploded EAR. If you put in relative paths with the appropriate number of `../` entries, then the path will resolve to anywhere on the filesystem you like, as long as it's navigable as a path relative to where the EAR is deployed (i.e. on windows, it has to be on the same drive).

Be aware, though, this is *not* standard behaviour, and isn't even guaranteed to work between different versions of JBoss.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't seem to work. As long as the relative paths are within the EAR structure it works. But fails when the paths lead to external jars.

Comment: Can you add the contents of your `application.xml` to the question?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE application PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD J2EE Application 1.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/application_1_3.dtd">
<application id="Application_ID">
 <display-name>FindingNemoEar</display-name>
 <module id="WebModule_1158763557391">
  <web>
   <web-uri>FindingNemoEarWeb.war</web-uri>
   <context-root>FindingNemo</context-root>
  </web>
 </module>
 <module>
  <java>../../abc.jar</java>
 </module>
</application>